# Unity WebGL Gameobject disabled from somewhere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

So, I have a update running on a monobehaviour script(Let's call it Script A) that's in the scene. This update fires a event, so other non-monobehaviour scripts can listen to this when they need a update for something. However, at the start of the app it runs the update on Script A for a short time, but after a while it randomly stops calling the update on Script A.

So I started to place some debugs in standard monobehaviour functions like awake, start, disable, enable etc. Turns out the object is disabled from somewhere without me using or calling it anywhere. This problem only occurs on WebGL. In the editor the OnDisable event is never called and the update keeps running fine.

I tried various fixes, like all the debugs logs everywhere, I tried debugging the stacktrace to find out what is calling this OnDisable, saidly this doesn't show in the WebGL console. It just says: StackTrace:

```
public class UpdateManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static UpdateManager _instance;
    public static UpdateManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = FindObjectOfType<UpdateManager>();

                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    GameObject updateManager = new GameObject("UpdateManager");
                    _instance = updateManager.AddComponent<UpdateManager>();
                }
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public delegate void OnUpdateEvent();
    public event OnUpdateEvent OnUpdate;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("UpdateManager: Awake!"); 
    }     

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("UpdateManager: Start!"); 
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log("UpdateManager: OnEnable!"); 
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Debug.Log("UpdateManager: OnDisable!, Stacktrace: " + UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility.ExtractStackTrace()); 
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("UpdateManager: Update!");
        OnUpdate?.Invoke();
    }
```

I would like to know what is disabling this object since I have no clue. Good to note here is that it's only disabled once at the beginning, and after I enable it again it runs fine for the remaining time.

The only places I call this script is in a static class somewhere:

```
    private static void initializeRefreshCycle(int expiresIn)
    {
        if (expiresIn > 0)
        {
            if (_refreshRoutine != null)
            {
                CoroutineManager.Instance.Stop(_refreshRoutine);
                _refreshRoutine = null;
            }

            DateTime expirationDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            _refreshTime = expirationDateTime.AddSeconds(expiresIn * 0.85f);
            Debug.Log(string.Format("<< API TOKEN WILL BE AUTOMATICALLY REFRESHED IN {0} SECONDS >>", expiresIn * 0.85f));

            UpdateManager.Instance.OnUpdate += OnUpdateEarly;
        }
    }
```

And then the function that actually listens to the call:

```
   public static void OnUpdateEarly()
    {
        if (!HasAlmostExpired) return;

        SSOCommunicator.RefreshToken(_refresh);
        UpdateManager.Instance.OnUpdate -= OnUpdateEarly;
    }
```

Looks like the first time it stops somewhere, and once it reached the subscribing again, it runs fine for the remaining time.

Comment: "It's only disabled once at the beginning, and after I enable it again it runs fine for the remaining time" -- How are you enabling it again from within the WebGL build?

Comment: Not specificely. I took the assumption it's enabled again because I re-subscribe to the event. Since that's the only thing I try to call. But on further notice that sounds stupid. The flow right now after it's disabled is as follows > I click on a button in the scene, which then loops through a couple of functions and eventually reaches the UpdateManager.Instance.OnUpdate += OnUpdateEarly;

Comment: Yeah it's best not to make assumptions like this. Doing so only makes tracking the problem down harder. I suspect you are ending up with more than one instance of your singleton, so most likely the "first" subscriptions are being lost.

Comment: That sounds logical yes. I thought about that. However, I do not see how I would end up with more than 1 instance. It always checks if there is already one. Besides, that does not explain the weird OnDisable call. Even weirder, only In WebGL

Comment: Are you doing anything multi-threaded ?

Comment: Also can you please post more code about how you are consuming this singleton?

Comment: Not that I know of. I posted the code where it's used. That's both in 1 (static) class That is called from an awake somewhere else. They subscribe to the instance, which should then see there is no instance yet, so it created one. That works (it then goes into the awake,startenable etc) it then runs the update for a little while and then stops and gets in ondisable... Hopefully its clear.

Comment: Also, when I click the said button in the game, it then goes through the same first function from the static class again (So it subscribes again) but through a different path. And when I do that, from that moment on it keeps working.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious to cause this behaviour. Just to make sure I understand, you have confirmed via `Debug.Log()` that the `UpdateManager` is getting disabled is that correct? And you are certain that nowhere in your code are you disabling or destroying it (because destroying it will trigger `OnDisabled)`? I'll try to reproduce this in a new test project tonight and get back to you if you haven't solved it by then.

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed it's disabled through the debug logs you see, and I'm 100% sure I don't call it anywhere myself. That's why I tried the stacktrace in the OnDisable(To find out what is calling it). Sadly that doesn't work in WebGL and in the editor everything runs fine(That's what bothers me the most) so there it never reaches the ondisable. Thanks in advance for the help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah you won't get a stacktrace from `OnDisable` because as far as I know it is called at a different time than the call to destroy or disable the object. I think Unity does some crazy reflection stuff.

Comment: Some last thing to note about what I tried is this: I tried pre-making the object in the scene. What then happens is the same, but after it tries to disable it, it continues calling the update, however that time the function that subscribed to the event doesn't listen to it. (while the debug.log from update is firing) So that sounds to me like there's 2 instances but It checks for a existing instance and again in the editor it runs fine.

Comment: Okay thanks for the extra info. In the meantime I would suggest you pre-make the object in the scene again and follow this advice for implementing the singleton and see if that fixes the issue: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116009/in-unity-how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-singleton-pattern

Comment: I will thankyou. The very last thing I need to note is that I'm running in locally through xampp on my localhost. Since I do not have easy acces to our live environment. But it seems verry unlikely that's the issue.

Comment: Did you try to directly debug it in a [development build](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-debugging.html) otherwise afaik stacktrace isn't printed.

Comment: Yes it's a development build, It just prints: UpdateManager: OnDisable!, Stacktrace:

Comment: Hi quick update for you. I tried to reproduce this with the code you have supplied and I do not get `OnDisable` called on the `UpdateManager` at all (in a WebGL build). I am running Unity 2019.1.10f1. Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: I actually did. Towards the end of yesterday night we found it it's a garbage collection issue. Since I would always call UpdateManager.Instance to call a function I never had a hard reference to that instance. So it was somehow destroyed at start only on WebGL. I solved it by keeping a hard reference in the awake of a script. So just having a simgple _updatamanager = Updatemanager.Instance solved it. Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: Interesting, glad you solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it's a garbage collection issue. Since I would always call UpdateManager.Instance to call a function I never had a hard reference to that instance. So it was somehow destroyed at start only on WebGL. I solved it by keeping a hard reference in the awake of a script. So just having a simgple _updatamanager = Updatemanager.Instance solved it.